# How do I integrate TestNG into an Android project?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, testng

Short question for those folks out there.

If I am starting from scratch, how exactly do I add TestNG unit tests to my existing Android project along with running them?

I'm also using IntelliJ (I know not Maven Android) to run the tests.

Thanks

Comment: I encountered a situation when I had to run existing testng test cases on android emulator, so I have created a tutorial outlining the way to do it. Hope somebody looking for such situation could save some time. read it on www.bullraider.com/java/android/random-android-articles/310-running-testng-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use testNG to run any kind of test cases you want.

You can just create a test package, and then a test class to start writing your tests.
Suppose that your class is called AndroidTests.java, you need to import testng and start writting your tests, just like this:

```
@Test   
public void test1() {       
 //Test logic here
 assert someAssert; 
}
```

Then, when you have enough test cases, you need to create your suite:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="My smoke suite" verbose="1" >
  <test name="My android tests">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.android.Androidtests"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

And finally run this suite from eclipse or using command line.

Please refer to more info in testNG doc:

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

And also take a look to Android test documentation:

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

Comment: This works for using the jar command line, I think it integrates directly into Maven though

Comment: Unfortunately the Android test documentation does not make any mention of TestNG...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the below dependencies to your gradle file:

```
androidTestCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:2.0.0'
 androidTestCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
```